# The address of a function matching a bool vs const void* overload

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I'm reading [Unexpected value using random number generator as a function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225614/unexpected-value-using-random-number-generator-as-a-function-in-c) and the comments and current answer say that the user is outputting the address of the function. That sounded reasonable. I assumed that a *function-to-pointer* conversion was occurring and therefore matching the `const void*` overload, however upon testing it myself, I get different results in GCC/Clang vs MSVC. The following test program:

```
#include <iostream>

void test()
{
}

void func(bool)
{
    std::cout << "bool";
}

void func(const void*)
{
    std::cout << "const void*";
}

int main()
{
    func(test);
}
```

outputs `bool` in GCC/Clang (<kbd>[`coliru`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d18a21ccde410f83)</kbd>)

and `const void*` in MSVC (<kbd>[`rextester`](http://rextester.com/live/QNFXT35340)</kbd> warning live collaboration link)

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says:

[conv.func]

> An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to a prvalue of type
>   "pointer to `T`." The result is a pointer to the function.

[conv.bool]

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. A prvalue of type
>   `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the
>   resulting value is `false`.

So a pointer which is not a null pointer value converted to bool should equal `true`, explaining the warning given by GCC/Clang.

Then Table 12 Conversions under [over.ics.scs] gives a function-to-pointer conversion an "Exact Match" rank and boolean conversions "Conversion" rank. [over.ics.rank]/4 then says:

> Standard conversion sequences are ordered by their ranks: an Exact
>   Match is a better conversion than a Promotion, which is a better
>   conversion than a Conversion. Two conversion sequences with the same
>   rank are indistinguishable unless one of the following rules applies:
>
> > — A conversion that does not convert a pointer, a pointer to member,
> >     or `std::nullptr_t` to `bool` is better than one that does.
> >
> > — [...]

I am not a language lawyer so I hope that I quoted the right sections.

However MSVC will call the `const void*` overload even if the `bool` overload is absent, and vice versa: GCC/Clang will call the `bool` overload even if the `const void*` overload is absent. So I'm not clear on the conversions here. Can somebody clear this up for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a bug (or extension) in MSVC. The standard does not define any standard conversions from a "pointer to function" to a "pointer to `void`."

It's hard to provide a quote for the *absence* of something, but the closest I can do is C++11 4.10/2 [conv.ptr]:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `T`,” **where `T` is an object type**, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>   to *cv* `void`”. The result of converting a “pointer to *cv* `T`” to a “pointer to *cv* `void`” points to the start of
>   the storage location where the object of type `T` resides, as if the object is a most derived object (1.8) of type
>   T (that is, not a base class subobject). The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the
>   destination type.

Together with 3.9/8 [basic.types]:

> An *object type* is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is **not a function type**, not a reference type, and not a
>   `void` type.

(emphasis mine)

Using [`/Za`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) to disable extensions will disable the non-standard conversion.

Comment: I assumed so. Doesn't that mean that the users on the linked question are wrong?

Comment: It's a non-standard MSVC extension. They have a bunch of these.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, softened the wording.

Comment: @remyabel Yes, the comments seem wrong. The answer is not wrong per se, just misleading: it says "this means the address", which is true. It's just that the address should convert to `bool` and not to `void*`.

Comment: It might be worthwhile adding that a function is not an object type § 1.8/1 "The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. An object is a
region of storage. [ Note: A function is not an object, regardless of whether or not it occupies storage in the
way that objects do. —end note ]"

Comment: @Angew You could also add [conv.func].

Comment: @Niall That should be self-explanatory.

Comment: @Niall True, but notes are non-normative.

Comment: @Columbo [conv.func] is in the question itself, I don't think it's worth repeating it.

Comment: @remyabel Do you have a quote for notes being non-normative? I keep hearing this, but never could find it in the standard. The closest I can get is 17.5.1.2/2 and 17.5.1.4/3, which apply to the standard library only and don't really conver the [*Note:* ... *-end note*] syntax.

Comment: @Angew Yes, forgot that.

Comment: @Angew No, I referred to [Are notes and examples in the core language specification of the C++ Standard non-normative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364398/are-notes-and-examples-in-the-core-language-specification-of-the-c-standard-no) It's probably being excessively pedantic, though.

Comment: @Niall although as mentioned notes are not normative I believe the requirements for an object laid out in section `1.8` do not apply to a function in particular lifetime and storage duration, I can't find a way to make the language in either of those sections work for a function and so this is consistent with the note.

Comment: @remyabel: If you want something definitely normative, C++11 3.9/8: "An *object type* is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not a void type."