# Using reinterpret_cast to cast a function to void*, why isn't it illegal?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, language-lawyer

This is a tangential follow up to my previous question [The address of a function matching a bool vs const void* overload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27226680/3920237). The answerer explained:

> The [C++11] standard does not define any standard conversions from a
>   "pointer to function" to a "pointer to `void`."
>
> It's hard to provide a quote for the *absence* of something, but the
>   closest I can do is C++11 4.10/2 [conv.ptr]:
>
> > A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `T`,” **where `T` is an object type**, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv*
> >     `void`”. The result of converting a “pointer to *cv* `T`” to a
> >     “pointer to *cv* `void`” points to the start of the storage location
> >     where the object of type `T` resides, as if the object is a most
> >     derived object (1.8) of type T (that is, not a base class subobject).
> >     The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the
> >     destination type.
>
> (emphasis mine)

Assuming `func` is declared `void func();`, if you do a C-style cast, i.e. `(void*) func`, the cast will be successful. `static_cast<void*>(func)` however is invalid, but `reinterpret_cast<void*>(func)` will be successful. What you cannot do however is convert the subsequently converted pointer back to its original type. For example,

Fine:

```
int main() {
  int* i;
  void* s = static_cast<void*>(i);
  i = static_cast<int*>(s);
  s = reinterpret_cast<void*>(i);
  i = reinterpret_cast<int*>(s);
}
```

Not fine:

```
void func() { }

int main() {
  void* s = reinterpret_cast<void*>(func);
  reinterpret_cast<decltype(func)>(s);
}
```

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) starts off by saying,

[expr.reinterpret.cast]

> The result of the expression `reinterpret_cast<T>(v)` is the result of
>   converting the expression `v` to type `T`. If `T` is an lvalue
>   reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is
>   an lvalue; if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is
>   an xvalue; otherwise, the result is a prvalue and the lvalue-to-rvalue
>   (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard
>   conversions are performed on the expression v. **Conversions that can be
>   performed explicitly using `reinterpret_cast` are listed below. No
>   other conversion can be performed explicitly using `reinterpret_cast`.**

I bolded the language that I believe is key here. The last part seems to imply that if the conversion is not listed, it's illegal. In brief summary, the allowed conversions are:

- A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it.
- A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer.
- A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type.
- An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.
- Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported.
- The null pointer value (4.10) is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.
- A prvalue of type "pointer to member of `X` of type `T1`" can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type "pointer to member of Y of type `T2`" if `T1` and `T`2 are both function types or both object types.
- An lvalue expression of type `T1` can be cast to the type "reference to `T2`" if an expression of type "pointer to `T1`" can be explicitly converted to the type "pointer to `T2`" using a reinterpret_cast.

`void*` is not a function pointer and objects don't have function or void type.

[basic.types]

> An object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a
>   function type, not a reference type, and not a void type.

So maybe I'm grasping at straws, but it seems `reinterpret_cast<void*>(func)` is illegal. However, on the other hand, [expr.static.cast]/5 says "Otherwise, the `static_cast` shall perform one of the conversions listed below. No other conversion shall be
performed explicitly using a `static_cast`." the key difference being "shall" and "can". Is this enough to make the `reinterpret_cast` legal or am I missing something else?

Comment: This works if you define a function pointer type ([demo](http://ideone.com/HNqcHh)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, that's explained in my answer.

Comment: @Columbo `func = ...` was irrelevant to the question since you can't assign to a function. Anyway, it appears that your deleted answer was correct. `v` is decayed, but `decltype(func)` isn't. Right?

Comment: @remyabel Firstly it isn't deleted anymore, secondly: Yes, that is correct :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<sub>(All quotes are from N3337 and are equivalent for every single draft until N4296 from there on, i.e. this answer is valid  at least for C++11 and C++14 **but not for C++03** as the first quote of this answer does not exist in there.)</sub>

[expr.reinterpret.cast]/8:

> **Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa
>   is conditionally-supported.** The meaning of such a conversion is
>   implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports
>   conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to
>   the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification,
>   shall yield the orignal pointer value.

This is contained in your listing. You argue that `void` is not an object type, but you didn't consider the crucial [basic.compound]/3:

> The type of **a pointer to `void`** or a pointer to an object type **is called an *object pointer type***.

(That is, a *object pointer type* is not necessarily a "pointer to object type" - standard terminology got you there.)

The only reason that

```
f = reinterpret_cast<decltype(f)>(s);
```

Isn't fine on GCC or Clang is that the target type, as opposed to the source expression, is *not* decayed - and you can clearly not cast `void*` to a function type. You need to make the target type a pointer to function, [**then it works**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/964d3801acf6319a).

Comment: Just to add to this fine answer, (1) the conditional support for converting between object and function pointers is very recent (C++11 or C++14); (2) but a requirement for such conversion has been part of Posix for a long time, and essential in the Windows API, so in essence the language has been catching up to reality here; (3) the separation of object pointers from functions pointers is tied to the Harvard architecture, which is still in use.

Comment: please do state which standard or draft you refer to.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf About the C++11 part: Yes, I didn't explicitly mention that since the question is tagged with C++11 anyway. I edited the answer, I used N3337.

Comment: Well at least the first quote was the same in C++11 (using N3290, the final draft). So, it entered in C++11.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The final draft of C++11 is N3337. And yes, I didn't find the quote in the C++03 FD, and added that to the head-note (is that the valid term?).

Comment: I don't think so, since N3337 is dated 16th january 2012. ;-)

Comment: Man that's really sneaky. :(

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf As far as I'm concerned, N3337 only contains editorial changes, making it equivalent in content but more pleasing to the eye.

Comment: @Columbo Doesn't that support exactly what Alf is claiming? Just because the changes are minor, and just because the meaning is the same, that doesn't mean there are no changes between C++11 and N3337. It's probably okay to use N3337 as a reference for C++11, but if someone takes the time to check what C++11 says, that's even better.

Comment: @hvd Yeah, I somehow thought that he implied that N3337 isn't a valid document to refer to C++11..

Comment: @hvd There are no "changes". The standard is not a PDF file, it's a set of rules. If those rules didn't change, neither has the standard, and both N3337 and N3296 refer to the same rule set (=standard).

Comment: @Columbo I don't follow. The standard is a text available in various forms, including PDF, and the exact wording of that text is an essential part of the standard. If you have a different text with different words, even if they mean the same thing, you don't have the standard.

Comment: @hvd Yes, but an editorial change is not allowed to change the exact meaning of the wording, is it? (Regardless of whether this makes a difference now).

Comment: @Columbo: Well my “I don’t think so” was in reference to the claim that a draft from 2012 could be the latest draft of C++11. It’s clearly not a draft of C++11: but yes, it’s a cleaned up version of C++11. I think you can safely use it as if it were actually the C++11 standard, with one exception that I see, namely that the editor removed (an unintended) `const` from the `&&` argument of the `scoped_allocator_adaptor` constructor.