# Is it safe to convert a template lambda to a `void *`?

Tags: c++, function, lambda, coroutine, reinterpret-cast

I'm working on implementing fibers using coroutines implemented in assembler. The coroutines work by `cocall` to change stack.

I'd like to expose this in C++ using a higher level interface, as `cocall` assembly can only handle a single `void*` argument.

In order to handle template lambdas, I've experimented with converting them to a `void*` and found that while it compiles and works, I was left wondering if it was safe to do so, assuming ownership semantics of the stack (which are preserved by fibers).

```
template <typename FunctionT>
struct Coentry
{
    static void coentry(void * arg)
    {
        // Is this safe?
        FunctionT * function = reinterpret_cast<FunctionT *>(arg);

        (*function)();
    }

    static void invoke(FunctionT function)
    {
        coentry(reinterpret_cast<void *>(&function));
    }
};

template <typename FunctionT>
void coentry(FunctionT function)
{
    Coentry<FunctionT>::invoke(function);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    auto f = [&]{
        std::cerr << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    };

    coentry(f);
}
```

Is this safe and additionally, is it efficient? By converting to a `void*` am I forcing the compiler to choose a less efficient representation?

Additionally, by invoking `coentry(void*)` on a different stack, but the original `invoke(FunctionT)` has returned, is there a chance that the stack might be invalid to resume? (would be similar to, say invoking within a `std::thread` I guess).

Comment: I don't know if it's valid or not, but it does make me scream internally. ***Why*** do you want to use a `void *` to pass around a callable object? Why not use the `FunctionT` template type? Or `std::function`?

Comment: I thought I explained it, but, because the current implementation of `cocall` is only able to handle one `void *` argument to the new stack.

Comment: You should at least add a `static_assert(sizeof(void *) == sizeof(&function));` because a pointer to function may not have the same size as pointer to void.

Comment: C does [not allow casting function pointers to `void*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579835/c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer) and I know it was alike in C++ - unless this changed recently (which I am not aware of), you are doing illegal stuff anyway...

Comment: @VTT shouldn't all pointers be the same size?

Comment: No, the size of pointers may vary. On x86 the size of a pointer to a regular function (lambda in your case is just a plain function as it does not capture anything) is the same as size of data pointer. But it may vary. Size of a pointer to a member function is much bigger. Also in this example you may actually pass a pointer to a lambda object, not to a function.

Comment: @Aconcagua Interesting, I have all warnings turned on including pedantic and don't get any messages about it being invalid.

Comment: @Aconcagua If I understood [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229578/using-reinterpret-cast-to-cast-a-function-to-void-why-isnt-it-illegal) correctly, it is allowed since C++11.

Comment: @ioquatix There can be some special cpus, where a function pointer and a data pointer do not have the same size (it has something to do with the size of the address-, data- and instruction- bus), but on the common cpus today they have the same size.

Comment: @Aconcagua - Fortunately, a lambda is not a function pointer, but an object.

Comment: @VTT - A lambda will not decay to a function pointer here. `FunctionT` will be deduced as the closure type of the lambda, an object.

Comment: @StoryTeller Interesting enough: Lambdas with empty capture list can be assigned to function pointers. What are these then? Indeed functions or some kind of compatible callable object?

Comment: @Aconcagua - Functors. Capture-less lambdas define a conversion to a function pointer, but they are still objects themselves. And in this context it makes a huge difference, because the deduced type is of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything done above is defined behaviour.  The only performance hit is that inlining something aliased thro7gh a void pointer could be slightly harder.

However, the lambda is an actual value, and if stored in automatic storage only lasts as long as the stored-in stack frame does.

You can fix this a number of ways.  `std::function` is one, another is to store the lambda in a `shared_ptr<void>` or `unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>`.  If you do not need type erasure, you can even store the lambda in a struct with deduced type.

The first two are easy.  The third;

```
template <typename FunctionT>
struct Coentry {
  FunctionT f;
  static void coentry(void * arg)
  {
     auto* self = reinterpret_cast<Coentry*>(arg);

    (self->f)();
  }
  Coentry(FunctionT fin):f(sts::move(fin)){}
};
template<class FunctionT>
Coentry<FunctionT> make_coentry( FunctionT f ){ return {std::move(f)}; }
```

now keep your `Coentry` around long enough until the task completes.

The details of how you manage lifetime depend on the structure of the rest of your problem.

Comment: This looks really interesting, I will experiment with this approach. I appreciate the code example as it's really helpful to see exactly what you mean.